# Passenger and Resque - Restarting on Deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, resque

I'm rolling out resque as my scheduler in my newest app, and noticed an interesting little quirk. The app we're building is just a REST API, and isn't being hit all the time. So, what it IS doing all the time is running some scheduled every two minute jobs to update the data it feeds out of the API.

Well, here's the quirk - until the application has been hit over HTTP at least once, the application doesn't restart, and the rescue workers are still working using the old version of the app.

I figure this is because with Passenger, when you just touch the tmp/restart.txt file, it just marks the app so that next time it gets hit by a request, it will restart. But if it DOESN'T get hit, it doesn't, yet, restart! Is there a way around this? Is there a way to tell passenger to restart an app and reload its environment right now, instead of the next time it receives an HTTP request?

Comment: Path of least resistance might be to have a monitoring service monitor your app, so it gets hit often and does restart.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I was over thinking it, this wasn't the problem at all - I just had a configuration wrong. Sorry!